# How to recover lost partitions

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, partitioning

I was trying to run the Windows diagnostic that ships with Sony laptops when it "froze" and I've lost my Linux 12.04 partition. I had VM's and software configured that I can't afford to lose. Please help me return to the state where I was before I tried running that Windows tool.

I am running a Lunux 13.10 LiveCD.

When I run the command: `sudo gpart /dev/hda`, I get the following output:

```
*** Fatal error: open(/dev/hda): No such file or directory.
```

However, when I run the command `sudo fdisk -l`, I get the following output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2d85c4ea

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    28887039    14442496   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2        28887040    29091839      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        29091840  1250260991   610584576    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gpart /dev/hda
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: You need to use something like Testdisk

Comment: What about `gparted /dev/sda`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like TestDisk to attempt to recover the partitions if the partition table was damaged.

They have an excellent guide [over at their website](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: The partition table revealed by `fdisk` shows that there are no Linux partitions and no empty space in which they might be "hiding." It looks like the tool that user248769 used tried to restore the system to factory defaults, wiping the Linux partition definition(s) in the process. With any luck, the Linux filesystem(s) remain undamaged and can be recovered; but if your luck is bad, you'll have to re-install Ubuntu and restore your personal data from backups. (You *do* have backups, right? *This* is why you should have them!)